# Quadratic Diophantine equation - Polynomial Time Cases

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, number-theory

In number theory, solving a Quadratic Diophantine equation (a, b, c constants)
$$
    a*x^2+b*y= c
$$ is an NP-Complete problem. Even for a=1, the problem remains NP-Complete.

The solution (x, y) are positive integers.

Query: What are the conditions on values of constants for which solving the problem is Polynomially feasible? Any link to the references?

Comment: Do you have a reference for its NP-completeness?

Comment: Garey and Johnson. A7.2. [AN8]

Comment: The requirement that $x,y$ be positive was not present in the initial iteration of the question, and it does change the problem.  It's important to state the problem correctly: its complexity can be sensitive to these kinds of details.

Comment: True. I missed that part (was wrong to assume that we are implicitly considering positive cases only).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't expect a complete characterization of all parameters that can be solved in polynomial time, but here are two cases where it can be solved in polynomial time:

If $b$ is prime, you can solve this in polynomial time by letting $x = \sqrt{c/a} \pmod{b}$ and then $y=(c-ax^2)/b$.  You can compute modular square roots in polynomial time by standard methods.

If $b$ has known factorization, similar methods can be used (use the Chinese remainder theorem).

Dealing with the requirements $x\ge 0,y \ge 0$ (which were added to the question after I wrote this answer) is more challenging.  When $b$ is prime, you can enumerate both modular square roots and see if either of them leads to a valid solution.  When $b$ is not prime but has known factorization, in the worst case this might require enumerating exponentially many modular square roots (though you might be able to randomly sample a few square roots and hope that at least one will lead to a positive solution).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was aware of the prime part, and the latter I understood as that even if we know the factorization of b it is still not guaranteed to be polynomial. 

Moreover, i am still concerned about some relation b/w 
b and c that makes the problem easier to solve.

Comment: @TheoryQuest1, when you already know of a partial answer, list it in the question originally.  Don't waste answerers' time -- tell us what approaches you've already considered, what solutions you've considered and rejected, what partial solutions you already know of.  ["Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!"](http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Acknowledge a formal apology and considering the remaining Questions will be more precise! I am still curious about the relation b/w b and c that makes the problem easier or hard. I am not sure about that part or any literature.