# Calculating Time Complexity of Quadratic Diophantine Equation

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np-complete

The particular quadratic Diophantine equation:

$$
R(a,b,c) \Leftrightarrow \exists X \exists Y :aX^2 + bY - c = 0
$$

is NP-complete. (a, b, and c are given in their binary representations. a, b, c, X, and Y are positive integers).

Kenneth L. Manders, Leonard M. Adleman: NP-Complete Decision Problems for Quadratic Polynomials. STOC 1976: 23-29

Since, I do not have the access to the stated paper, can someone help with how the time complexity (clearly exponential) varies/depends on the size of a, b, and c?

Comment: [Related question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/43077/quadratic-diophantine-equation-polynomial-time-cases).

Comment: Thanks.. that Q is different.. the Q I have is different here:

Let a, b, c be some constants in a Quadratic Diophantine Equation. How will the computational complexity of the problem be affected w.r.t. the changing (lets assume doubling) the size (Number of Bits) in these cases:

1. just 'a'
2. just 'b'
3. just 'c'

Comment: I read diagonally the paper and I didn't see any formula for the complexity, they just said things like "Moreover, we can obtain all quantities needed deterministically within polynomial time in the length of the input" etc..